# V-model com Vuex push no array que está na store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Olá, sou novo com vuex e preciso de um auxílio:

abaixo está um pedaço do meu código:

```
<v-btn icon color="purple darken-2" @click="addKeyNames"
                ><v-icon> mdi-plus-circle-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>

          <v-row v-for="(keyNamesLocal, index) in keyName" v-bind:key="index">
            <v-col id="chave" cols="12" md="4">
              <ValidationProvider
                v-slot="{ errors }"
                name="Nome da Chave"
                rules="required|max:100"
                required
              >
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="keyNamesLocal.name"
                  label="Nome da Chave"
                  :error-messages="errors"
                  :counter="100"
                  required
                />
              </ValidationProvider>
            </v-col>

            <v-col id="chave" cols="12" md="1">
              <v-btn
                icon
                large
                color="purple darken-2"
                @click="removeKeyName(index)"
              >
                <v-icon>mdi-delete-forever-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
```

vuex:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    api: {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      description: "",
      developer: "",
      legacy: "",
      endpoint: "",
      releaseDate: "",
      project: "",
      keyNames: [],
      uraType: "",
      xmlOutput: "",
      xmlInput: "",
      codeReturn: "",
      descriptionReturn: "",
      errorTypeReturn: "",
      xmlCodeReturn: "",
      segmentation: ["Controle", "Pós", "Pré", "Next", "Nenhuma"],
      attachment: [],
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_API(state, payload) {
      state.api = Object.assign(state.api, payload);
    },
    createKeyName(state, payload) {
      state.api.keyNames = payload
    },
```

Preciso que meu text-field label: Nome da Chave, grave chaves dentro do meu array (api.keyNames na store), porém está me retornando um erro.

Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

Answer (score 0):

Vai dar trabalho mais vou tentar te ajudar kkkkkkkk....
Quando se está utilizando vuex você não deve "mutar" o state sem utilizar-se de alguma `mutation`, e isso o seu `v-model` está fazendo, em outras palavras, usando vuex, não use v-model nos campos do seu vuex...
troque o `v-model` por `:value`, o seu `v-text-field` ficará assim:

```
 <v-text-field
  :value="keyNamesLocal.name"
   label="Nome da Chave"
   :error-messages="errors"
   :counter="100"
   required
   @input="setKeyName($event)"
                />
```

o @input que eu adicionei que deverá chamar uma mutation sua, que está no vuex, que irá alterar o seu `keyNamesLocal.name` e o nome dessa mutation eu dei de `setKeyName`,primeiro vamos declarar nosso atributo `keyName`...

```
 api: {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      description: "",
      developer: "",
      legacy: "",
      endpoint: "",
      releaseDate: "",
      project: "",
      keyNames: [],
      uraType: "",
      xmlOutput: "",
      xmlInput: "",
      codeReturn: "",
      descriptionReturn: "",
      errorTypeReturn: "",
      xmlCodeReturn: "",
      segmentation: ["Controle", "Pós", "Pré", "Next", "Nenhuma"],
      attachment: [],
      keyname : "",
    },
```

agora vamos criá-la...

```
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_API(state, payload) {
      state.api = Object.assign(state.api, payload);
    },
    createKeyName(state, payload) {
      state.api.keyNames = payload;
    },
    setKeyName(state, payload) {
      state.api.keyName = payload;
    },
```

depois de criá-la não esqueça de adicionar no seu mapMutations,
e agora no seu botão que adiciona você parece já ter a mutation pronta com o nome `addKeyNames`, sem o código todo não tenho como ter certeza...

```
<v-btn icon color="purple darken-2" @click="addKeyNames"
                ><v-icon> mdi-plus-circle-outline</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
```

mas caso não tenha adicione a suas mutations:

```
 mutations: {
        UPDATE_API(state, payload) {
          state.api = Object.assign(state.api, payload);
        },
        createKeyName(state, payload) {
          state.api.keyNames = payload;
        },
        setKeyName(state, payload) {
          state.api.keyName = payload;
        },
         addKeyNames(state) {
          state.api.keyNames.push(state.api.keyName);
        },
```

Comment: Agradeço a explicação e ajuda Germano, mas acho que não me expressei corretamente. O que eu preciso na verdade é capturar do usuário nomes(strings) e salvar no meu array keyNames que está no meu objeto pai (api) dentro da minha store. Seria um push em um array de strings